# Access to protected range via google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create function where somebody put something in one cell, the date of this operation is going in another cell. So I made this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var data = new Date();
if (
e.source.getSheetName() == "sheet" &&
e.range.columnStart == 7 &&
e.range.columnEnd == 7 
//e.range.rowStart >= 2 &&
//e.range.rowEnd <= 5000
) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PRODUKCJA MODELE");
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

var range = e.range.getValue();

var cell = e.range.getRow();
if(range)
{
  ss.getRange(cell, 2).setValue(new Date());
}    
else
{
  ss.getRange(cell, 2).setValue("");
}
}

}
```

And it wroks fine. But the problem is there are several users that cannot modify a cell with date, so I make it protected and blocked for normal users. And there is my problem, when I did it, the script is no longer working. Can somebody point me atleast a direction how can i do it? I tried to temporary unlock the range in scripts but it make no sense because nornal user cannot do that anyway.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Use "Installable triggers"

Comment: I don't really see how it should help me. I only want to add this date when somebody edits one column, not whole spreadsheet.

Comment: Scripts run as "the user at the keyboard", who doesn't have access to protected ranges. "installable triggers" run as "user who created the trigger", say owner. So, it'll run under the authorization of owner.

Comment: Oh my God... 
At first look, I didn't even try to understand those installable triggers. Now when I did, it totally did my job. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been sovled. Installable triggers did the job. All I had to do is set a triggare with event and set "on Edit".